# How to get the following date with a specific day / month according to a certain day cursor in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

I have a table in **BigQuery** tracking transactions that I made and I want to be able to easily calculate the next billing date from today.
I thus have the following fields:

- Date_of_first_transaction
- Current_Date
- Payment_type (Yearly, Monthly, Weekly, Daily)

According to the type of payment I want to be able to easily calculate the next billing date.

For example if `Date_of_first_transaction = "2019-06-11"` and `Current_Date = "2021-04-27"` and `Payment_type = "Yearly"` so my next billing date will be `"2021-06-11"`.

Another example: if `Date_of_first_transaction = "2020-12-13"` and `Current_Date = "2021-04-27"` and `Payment_type = "Monthly"` so my next billing date will be `"2021-05-13"`.

I was wondering how I can do that properly, without tones of `CASE WHEN... THEN ... END`

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: there are really two questions here: 1) `how to easily calculate next billing date?` and 2) `how I can do that properly, without tones of CASE WHEN... THEN ... END ?` - which one is your focus here? it usually should be one question per post otherwise you have less chances to get answer. I would loved to jump in - but confused on which exactly question to answer?

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you may be able to use `date_diff()` and `date_add()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when payment_type = 'yearly'
             then date_add(date_of_first_transaction,
                           interval (1 + date_diff(current_date, date_of_first_transaction, year)) year)
             when payment_type = 'monthly'
             then date_add(date_of_first_transaction,
                           interval (1 + date_diff(current_date, date_of_first_transaction, month)) month)
             when payment_type = 'weekly'
             then date_add(date_of_first_transaction,
                           interval (1 + date_diff(current_date, date_of_first_transaction, week)) week)
             when payment_type = 'daily'
             then date_add(date_of_first_transaction,
                           interval (1 + date_diff(current_date, date_of_first_transaction, day)) day)
        end)     
from t;
```

Note:  Definitely test this out.  This may not be exactly what you want because `date_diff()` returns the number of date boundaries between two values.

Comment: It does work when the day of `date_of_first_transaction` is smaller than the `current_date` day (for example `date_of_first_transaction = 2020-06-11` and `current_date = 2021-04-27` and `payment_type = monthly` it returns `2021-05-11`) but when the day of `date_of_first_transaction` is higher then it is false (for example `date_of_first_transaction = 2021-01-31` and `current_date = 2021-04-27` and `payment_type = monthly` it returns `2021-05-31` and it should be `2021-04-31`) @GordonLinoff